# export form WebGL to .obj

Tags: export, webgl

I've seen a lot of explanations for how to import .obj files into webGL, but I was wondering if there was a way to do the opposite? I have a webGL file that can randomly generate shapes, and I want to export them as .obj files. Is there a way to do this?

Or, if not, is there another programming format that I should recreate my code with that does have this ability? Thank you.

Comment: Three.js have a lot of importers that could be adapted to export from the webgl scene. Put in a feature request @ http://threejs.org